# Is this an example of a backwards pawn?

Tags: pawns

1. e4 e5
2. d3

At this point, if d3 advances, say at 3. d4 it does not control d4, it is controlled by a sentry (an enemy pawn controlling d4) and is adjacent and behind a same colored pawn at e4.

Is the d3 pawn backwards? I was told no, because it is supported by c2, but Wikpedia's definition of a backwards pawn doesn't care about a backward's pawn's support, only the support it has moving forward.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pawn on `d3` is not backwards since (as you say) it is protected by another pawn.

There must be something missing from Wikipedia's definition. Later on the article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_pawn) contradicts itself.

> Also, the opponent can place a piece, usually a knight, on the hole in front of the pawn without any risk of a pawn driving it away.

In your example, if black puts a knight on `d4`, the pawn move `c3`will drive it away.

Comment: Thanks, I had suspected this was true (that a backwards pawn also has to be unprotected itself) and felt there was something I was missing from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_pawn

Comment: Could someone make an edit to Wikipedia's entry? In versions in other languages it is mentioned that neighboring pawns are further advanced.

Comment: I quickly made an edit to add in the word "Unsupported"   a backward pawn is an unsupported pawn that is behind a pawn of the same color on an adjacent file and that cannot be advanced without loss of material, usually the backward pawn itself. But now i wonder if a backwards pawn must also have the ability to advance regardless of who controls its stop square.